# Aggregate function's return value

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query to get "posts" along with all tags associated with it:

```
SELECT 
posts.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) tags
FROM
posts
LEFT JOIN relation ON relation.post_id  = posts.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = relation.tag_id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

(This is only a example code).

If no tags exists, "tags" field will return NULL. How to change this NULL value to empty string ?

We can use `SELECT posts.*, IF(ISNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name)),'',GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name)) AS tags ....`

But it GROUP_CONCATs two times. Correct ? What is the best method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the `if` by using [COASLESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT 
  posts.*,
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name),'') AS tags
FROM
  posts
  LEFT JOIN relation ON relation.post_id  = posts.id
  LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = relation.tag_id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

MySQL also supports `IFNULL` which does the same, but IFNULL only allows 2 parameters, not an unlimited number as `COALESCE` does.

Comment: thankyou. That works.
But can you tell me the working of it? GROUP_CONCAT() will return concatenated value. So we should check this returned value. But in your code you placed it inside. Can you please explain working of this ?
**EDIT**: You edited `IFNULL` code ?

Comment: It will return the concatenated value of exactly one `NULL`. COALESCE returns the first value that isn't NULL and in this case the list is just two elements, NULL and ''.... '' is the first value that is not NULL.

Comment: @VppMan, I updated the question, after I reread your question.

Comment: thankyou andreas. I understood your explanation about "COALESCE". But in the previous code(before editing) IFNULL is used inside aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT. I did not follow that. Can you please explain that ?

Comment: @Johan But that code also worked when i tested in phpmyadmin. Is it wrong way ?

Comment: Putting the `ifnull` inside the `group_concat` is less efficient. Also if you get multiple hits, you end up with a result of `,,,,` being returned, rather than the empty string.

Comment: so `ifnull` inside `group_concat` will check each tag record whether it is null and returns empty string if null. So all this will be concatenated by `group_concat`, resulting, empty strings separated by commas. Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

how about using coalesce
it simply returns the first non-null value in a series of values

```
SELECT 
posts.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(coalesce(tags.tag_name,'')) tags
FROM
posts
LEFT JOIN relation ON relation.post_id  = posts.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = relation.tag_id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me the difference when coalesce() is used inside and outside GROUP_CONCAT() ? You used inside it.In above answer, Johan used it outside.

Comment: in this situation you could end up with X,Y,,Z  I'm not sure how group_concat with an outer coalesce will process when SOME of the tags are null.  will X,Y,,Z be returned or will NULL be returned becuase ONE of the values is null... I don't know what Group_concat does without testing.